# Redmine 2.2.3 Wiki editor does not show markup-language

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, wiki, redmine, markup

I used Redmine 2 years ago and loved the markup editor to write wiki articles. Now we installed Redmine 2.2.3 in a new enviroment. But the editor changed and now there is a WYSIWYG-Editor.

Is there any option to get the old markup editor back?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1):

Change text formatting (Administration > Settings > General > Text formatting) to "Textile".